# Upgrading java version to use latest from JDK 8

Tags: java, macos, javac

I just downloaded the latest JDK 8 from Oracle and ran the installer on Mac OS X.

However, even after restarting, I see I'm still on version 1.6

```
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_65"
```

What do I do to get it to use version 1.8?

Comment: try to delete the 1.6 version from your mac ?

Comment: have you set java_home path ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the Java optional package or Oracle JDK installed, adding the following line **~/.bash_profile** file will set the environment variable accordingly.

```
export JAVA_HOME="$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)"
```